# Java, JVM memory area Operating principle

Tags: java, memory, static, jvm, instance

When declaring a collection, it exists in the heap, but how does it behave when you insert an instance in the static area? Please explain to me about JVM memory area.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static int n = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<Object> a = new ArrayList<Object>();
        a.add(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: The instance or the object will reside in the Heap. The reference to it resides in the Stack. So, when the method finishes, the reference is popped off the Stack. So, the instance is available for Garbage Collection from the Heap.

Comment: @anacron Thank you so much. You're very smart!

Comment: `int` is a primitive and not an instance of a class. If `n` were an instance of a class it would have no impact on `a`. `a` is still eligible for collection once it goes out of scope.